# Invalid Syntax for PEP-8

Tags: python-3.x, pep8

I'm receiving a notification that advised the below script is not PEP-8:

```
example_var = print('whoa')
```

Output:

```
[E] invalid syntax.
```

It's showing that the error is a result of the first parentheses in the print statement, but nothing looks off to me.

```
example_var = print('whoa')
example_var
```

Comment: What version of pep8?

Comment: What version of pep8 and python are you running?

Comment: I am running python 3.5 and using Pygments 2.1.3 to identify pep8 syntax errors